# What is causing "Outlet is not activated" error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to create a workflow of 4 steps in my webapp, when I load the app, I can navigate from step 1 to step 4 without problem, then, I go back to step 1 without reloading the app and I do the same path from step 1 to step 4, arriving to step 4 (for the second time), I got a `Outlet is not activated` error as shown below. The resulting of this error is that any of my datas are shown on the step 4.
So my question is What could cause that error ?

Here is the error

```
ERROR Error: Outlet is not activated
    at Object.get component [as component] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:110083:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115121:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115111:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115111:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:115111:40)
```

**wizard.component.html**

```
<app-wizard-steps></app-wizard-steps>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**wizard.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard',
  templateUrl: './wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wizard.component.scss']
})
export class WizardComponent {
}
```

```js
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {WizardComponent} from './wizard.component';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {WizardGuard} from './wizard.guard';
import {ArchitectureStepRouteGuard} from './steps/architecture-step/architecture-step.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WizardComponent,
    canActivate: [WizardGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'project-name-step',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'project-name-step',
        data: {stepNumber: 1},
        loadChildren: () => import('./steps/project-name-step/project-name-step.module').then(m => m.ProjectNameStepModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'architecture-step/:id',
        data: {stepNumber: 2},
        loadChildren: () => import('./steps/architecture-step/architecture-step.module').then(m => m.ArchitectureStepModule),
        canActivate: [ArchitectureStepRouteGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'adjustments-step/:id',
        data: {stepNumber: 3},
        loadChildren: () => import('./steps/adjustments-step/adjustments-step.module').then(m => m.AdjustmentsStepModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'results-step/:id',
        data: {stepNumber: 4},
        loadChildren: () => import('./steps/results-step/results-step.module').then(m => m.ResultsStepModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WizardRoutingModule {
}
```

**wizard.module.ts**

```js
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {AdjustmentsStepRouteGuard} from './steps/adjustments-step/adjustments-step.guard';
import {ArchitectureStepRouteGuard} from './steps/architecture-step/architecture-step.guard';
import {ProjectNameStepRouteGuard} from './steps/project-name-step/project-name-step.guard';
import {ResultsStepRouteGuard} from './steps/results-step/results-step.guard';
import * as fromWizardStore from './store/wizard';
import * as fromTSEProjectStore from './store/TSEProject';
import {TSEProjectsEffects} from './store/TSEProject/effects/TSEProject.effects';
import {WizardStepsComponent} from './wizard-steps/wizard-steps.component';
import {WizardComponent} from './wizard.component';
import {WizardRoutingModule} from './wizard.routing.module';
import {WizardNavigationModule} from './wizard-navigation/wizard-navigation.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    WizardRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('wizard', fromWizardStore.reducer),
    StoreModule.forFeature('TSEProject', fromTSEProjectStore.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([TSEProjectsEffects]),
    TranslateModule,
    WizardNavigationModule
  ],
  declarations: [WizardComponent, WizardStepsComponent],
  providers: [ProjectNameStepRouteGuard, ArchitectureStepRouteGuard, AdjustmentsStepRouteGuard, ResultsStepRouteGuard]
})
export class WizardModule {
}
```

Comment: Why do you want <router-outlet></router-outlet> in wizard.component.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that my "4 steps wizard" is in a larger application, so I display my steps via this router-outlet

Comment: Add RouterModule and routes in in module

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a route without `component`, `redirectoTo` or `children`:

Try to add some component to an empty route:

```
{ path: '', component: FooComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482).

Try to add some `foo` instead of empty path:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'foo',
    component: WizardComponent,
    canActivate: [WizardGuard],
    children: [
        // ...the other code is omitted for the brevity
    ]
}
```

and then rewrite url:

```
<a [routerLink]="['wizard/load']"> Wizard </a>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I edited my post with the routes infos, the route seems to be well defined, and the weird part is that the bug only appears when I go on the step for the second time, but first time everything is fine.

Comment: @Agudolive could you show `wizard.module.ts`? or some reproducible error at [stackblitz.com](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: I added the source in my post, the project is pretty big and I don't know what is causing the error, so Stackblitz is difficult now

Comment: I navigate using this.router.navigate(['adjustments-step', a.project.id], {relativeTo: a.route.parent.parent}) How can I adjust it to my new url (with `foo`)

Comment: @Agudolive try to add like that `['adjustments-step', 'foo', a.project.id], {relativeTo: a.route.parent.parent}) `